# Cannot connect to amazon AWS EMR via the command line interface

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, configuration, amazon-s3, emr

I am running into problems when I am trying to run a mapreduce job on AWS via the command line. I have to perform a large set of steps (approx 100) that are all chained to each other. Since I am not looking forward to configuring that by hand with the AWS graphic interface, I am trying to get it done with the CLI.

However, even the most easy command does not work:

```
$ aws emr list-clusters
hostname 'elasticmapreduce.us-west-1.amazonaws.com' doesn't match u'us-west-1.elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com'
```

On S3 my configurations seem to work fine, since this command creates the bucket without any problems:

```
$ aws s3 mb s3://randombigdatabucket
```

These are my configurations:

```
$ aws configure list 
Name                    Value             Type    Location
----                    -----             ----    --------
profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************fooo shared-credentials-file    
secret_key     ****************fooo shared-credentials-file    
region                us-west-1      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

I hope somebody can help me out with this one!

Comment: Are you using the latest version of AWS CLI ? 1.6.6 as of today.

Comment: Nope! I was still using the 1.6.5 I installed a few days ago, thanks! One quick question: do you know if any clusters that are started using the CLI are also (eventually) visible in the graphical interface online?

Comment: Both CLI and web console are front end on top of the API. Anything you do with one,should be visible with the second.  Providing you are using the same IAM user

Comment: Does 1.6.6 solves your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to install AWS CLI v1.6.6 or later